# Structure array dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, matlab-struct

Is there a difference between a 1x3 structure array and a 3x1 structure array?  From what I can see, there doesn't appear to be but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a difference, but it will only matter some of the time. This holds true for numeric arrays as well so I will use these in my examples below for brevity.

For [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) it won't matter whether for a row or column vector.

```
a = [4, 5, 6];
b = a.';

a(1) == b(1)
a(2) == b(2)
a(3) == b(3)
```

If you use two dimensions to index it though, it will matter.

```
% Will work
a(1, 3)

% Won't work
a(3, 1)

% Will Work
b(3, 1)

% Won't work
b(1, 3)
```

The biggest time it matters is when you go to combine it with another `struct`. The dimensions must allow for concatenation.

```
a = [1 2 3];
b = a.';

% Cannot horizontally concatenate something with 1 row with something with 3 rows
[a, b]

% You need to make sure they both have the same # of rows
[a, a]   % or [a, b.']
```